# Passing parameter through a function for a swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I want to pass two parameters, the swipe gesture, and an AVPlayerLayer through a parameter when a gesture is performed. This is what I've tried:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
let slideDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTest(gesture: slideDown, playerLayer: playerLayer)))
slideDown.direction = .down
addGestureRecognizer(slideDown)
```

This is the dismissTest function:

```
@objc func dismissTest(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer, playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer) {
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    if let theWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        gesture.view?.frame = CGRect(x:theWindow.frame.width - 115 , y: theWindow.frame.height - 208, width: 100 , height: 178)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:theWindow.frame.width - 115 , y: theWindow.frame.height - 208, width: 100 , height: 178)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when trying this i get the error:

> Variable used within its own initial value

If I don't want to pass the AVPlayerLayer Parameter this is what I do and it works fine:

```
let slideDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTest(gesture:)))
        slideDown.direction = .down
        addGestureRecognizer(slideDown)



    @objc func dismissTest(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("true")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        if let theWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            gesture.view?.frame = CGRect(x:theWindow.frame.width - 115 , y: theWindow.frame.height - 208, width: 100 , height: 178)
        }
    }
}
```

When i add the AVPlayerLayer parameter, everything just messes up and I get errors such as missing parameter. How can I change the function so it allows me to pass both the gesture parameter and AVPlayerLayer Parameter?

Comment: Have you declared PlayerLayer as a constant?

Comment: yes i just edited the code to show you how I did

Comment: Try changing let playerLayer to var playerLayer

Comment: Short answer: You can't do that. `target/action` provides either no parameter or **one** parameter (the affected UI element)

Comment: Okay do I have any other option, so i can pass two parameters?

Comment: As already mentioned *passing* multiple parameters is impossible. You could use a property as temporary variable.